# How to copy files to wwwroot directory using copy "Copy Files To azure" pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-appservice

I am using azure devops to host my angular application on azure appservice and it's working great. I have two files in my src folder of project and I want to move or paste those files into the **wwwroot** directory where my application's published code is placed.

If I add dist in the Target Folder of "Copy Files To" then files copying to the **dist** folder as you can see in the second image. But If i place wwwroot then after completion of this pipeline the message shows that Copying "D:\a\1\s\src\server.js to wwwroot\server.js" but if i see the directory then these files are not showing any where. I have tried `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` in the Target Folder also but it's not working though. How can i copy the files from src to wwwroot?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you tell where do you publish your angular app? If you just place dist it will go to `System.DefaultWorkingDirectory/dist` which is different than 'Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory`.

Comment: Hi, how about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question, If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: Please check if below answer resolves your issue. If it can't help, would you please share the whole build definitions of your pipeline here?

Answer (score 1):

1.You should make sure the target folder and the folder to publish is the same folder.

For example: If you copy those two files directly into `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`, then your `Publish Artifact Task`'s `Path To Publish` should also be `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`.

2.Then in your `Azure App Service Deploy` task(if this task is in release pipeline), you should make sure the path is correct to find the drop folder:

[image]

(Use the button to find the artifact path, and add `/drop`)

3.Finally in Azure Web Portal, navigate to `App Service=>Configurations=>Virtual path` and make sure the physical path is `wwwroot` instead of `wwwroot\dist`:

[image]

Then it works well on my side to deploy the files in wwwroot folder.